# How to create a Vert.x ReadStream from an InputStream

Tags: java, vert.x, reactivex

I would like to stream the stdout of a local process to a Vert.x HttpResponse.

To do it I think I have to stream/convert/pipe a `java.io.InputStream` (which streams the process stdout) to an `io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream` and then I can pipe the `ReadStream` to the `HttpResponse`.

I'm searching for a solution that has a small memory impact, so read the whole stdout in memory and then flush it to the HttpResponse is not possible.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve by that. ReadStream represent large, but finite amount of data. `System.out` is an infinite stream. The result would be that your HttpResponse never closes.

Comment: I think OP wants to start a process (e.g. via ProcessBuilder) and pipe the output to the HttpResponse rather than piping System.out to the HttpResponse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out:

https://gist.github.com/Stwissel/a7f8ce79785afd49eb2ced69b56335de

Here is how I used it:

```
InputStream is = ...
          AsyncInputStream ais = new AsyncInputStream(
            vertx, vertx.getOrCreateContext(), is);
          ais.pipeTo(response);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the `OutputToReadStream` class from the [vertx-java.io](https://github.com/cloudonix/vertx-java.io) library (I am the author):

```java
new OutputToReadStream(vertx).wrap(inputStream).pipeTo(response);
```